# Is it possible to determine the position of the laminar-turbulent transition of a boundary-layer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

Can the exact position of the transition point from laminar to turbulent flow be calculated when working with flat plates? Or can the position only be estimated based on the common Reynold's numbers associated with the transition point?

Answer (score 1):

Using computer simulations, it is possible to estimate the likely position of a laminar-to-turbulent transition. In fact, computer modeling of fluid flow has gotten so good in recent years that almost no one uses scale models of aircraft in wind tunnels any more to guide the development of their designs.

That said, note however that in practice, transitions of this sort can be triggered by unexpected air motions within the stream of air flowing over the object, or by small imperfections in the surface of your flat plate (think: rain droplets, squashed insects, etc.)- or the phase of the moon, the color of your socks, etc.

So... having modeled the location of the laminar-to-turbulent transition point, you still need to fly a test article through a rainstorm or a swarm of insects and see what happens, while controlling for lunar phase and sock color.